# Validacion de formulario Utilizando Jquery

Tags: html, mvc, cshtml

Estoy intentando Validar los campos de input del formulario utilizando Jquery , sin embargo no he podido conseguir mis resultados despues de varios intentos . El resultado que quiero conseguir es un texto al lado de las cajas que indique que o llenen la caja o ingresen datos validos.

he tratado de implementar Jquery de la siguientes maneras:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>add</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myForm").validate({
            rules: {
                TxtNombre: {
                    required: true
                },
                TxtApellidos: {
                    required: true
                },
                TxtCel: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                inputEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                InputURL: {
                    required: true,
                    url: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                TxtNombre: {
                    required: "Por favor, ingrese su nombre"
                },
                TxtApellidos: {
                    required: "Por favor, ingrese sus apellidos"
                },
                TxtCel: {
                    required: "Por favor, ingrese su número de teléfono",
                    minlength: "Su número de teléfono debe tener 8 dígitos"
                },
                inputEmail: {
                    required: "Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico",
                    email: "Por favor, ingrese un correo electrónico válido"
                },
                InputURL: {
                    required: "Por favor, ingrese la URL de su foto",
                    url: "Por favor, ingrese una URL válida"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

segun tengo entendido deberia de enseñar mensajes de error cada vez que presiono submit , sin embargo eso no pasa.

Mi ultimo intento fue:

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    TxtNombre: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    TxtApellidos: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    TxtCel: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 10
                    },
                    inputEmail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    InputURL: {
                        required: true,
                        url: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    TxtNombre: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese su nombre"
                    },
                    TxtApellidos: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese sus apellidos"
                    },
                    TxtCel: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese su número de teléfono",
                        minlength: "Su número de teléfono debe tener al menos 8 dígitos"
                    },
                    inputEmail: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico",
                        email: "Por favor, ingrese un correo electrónico válido"
                    },
                    InputURL: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese la URL de su foto",
                        url: "Por favor, ingrese una URL válida"
                    }
                },
                onfocusout: function (element) {
                    this.element(element);
                }
            });
        });


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    TxtNombre: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    TxtApellidos: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    TxtCel: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 10
                    },
                    inputEmail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    InputURL: {
                        required: true,
                        url: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    TxtNombre: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese su nombre"
                    },
                    TxtApellidos: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese sus apellidos"
                    },
                    TxtCel: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese su número de teléfono",
                        minlength: "Su número de teléfono debe tener al menos 8 dígitos"
                    },
                    inputEmail: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico",
                        email: "Por favor, ingrese un correo electrónico válido"
                    },
                    InputURL: {
                        required: "Por favor, ingrese la URL de su foto",
                        url: "Por favor, ingrese una URL válida"
                    }
                },
                onfocusout: function (element) {
                    this.element(element);
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    //Ni idea ahora
                    alert('El formulario se envió correctamente!');
                    form.submit(); // Si deseas enviar el formulario después de la validación exitosa
                    return false; // Si no deseas enviar el formulario después de la validación exitosa
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<div class="container">
    <form class="row" id="myForm">
        <!-- Lado izquierdo -->
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>
                <label for="TxtNombre" class="form-label">Nombres</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TxtNombre" name="TxtNombre">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-4">
                <label for="genero">Genero</label>
                <select class="form-select" id="genero" name="genero" aria-label="Seleccionar">
                    <option value="">Seleccione su genero</option>
                    <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                    <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-4">
                <label for="sangre">Tipo de Sangre</label>
                <select class="form-select" id="sangre" name="sangre" aria-label="Seleccionar">
                    <option value="">Seleccione su tipo de sangre</option>
                    <option value="O+">O+</option>
                    <option value="O-">O-</option>
                    <option value="A+">A+</option>
                    <option value="A-">A-</option>
                    <option value="B+">B+</option>
                    <option value="B-">B-</option>
                    <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                    <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Lado derecho -->
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>
                <label for="TxtApellidos" class="form-label">Apellidos</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TxtApellidos" name="TxtApellidos">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="TxtCel" class="form-label">Telefono Personal</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="TxtCel" name="TxtCel">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="InputURL" class="form-label">Fotografia</label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="InputURL" name="InputURL">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

cualquier aclaracion seria de gran ayuda ya que no tengo mucha experiencia con cshtml. Algo a mencionar que tengo los nuggets / librerias las tengo instaladas , es un proyecto MVC , utilizando capas en .net framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualiza el jquery validation. Cambia:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

por:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Pon algo de estilos:

```
       <style>
        form .error{
           color: red;
         }
        
         input.error{
          border-color: red;
         }
      </style>
```